# Remove whole Entry row (5 boxes) in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have button and a function which creates 5 Entry boxes in newline every time you click it

```
def __init__(self, master):
    [...]
    self.rows_list = 2
    self.new_button = ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='Add', command=self.new_window).grid(column=5, row=0)

def new_window(self):
    rows = self.rows_list
    labels = 5
    for x in range(labels):
        ttk.Entry(self.tab1).grid(column=int(x), row=rows)
    self.rows_list += 1
```

I am struggling with making REMOVE button removing last row. Tried multiple "internet solutions" but non of them helped.

Comment: Can you post a working program which does not work? .-)

Comment: Save them to a list, iterate over the list to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, since you have `self.row_list` to be used as the next row that those new entries be created, you can use this variable to get the widgets in the last row and destroy them:

```py
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...

        self.rows_list = 2
        ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='Add', command=self.new_window).grid(column=5, row=0)
        ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='Remove', command=self.remove_row).grid(column=6, row=0)

    ...

    def remove_row(self):
        if self.rows_list > 2:
            # get widgets in last row
            widgets = self.tab1.grid_slaves(row=self.rows_list-1)
            # and destroy them
            for w in widgets:
                w.destroy()
            # update self.rows_list
            self.rows_list -= 1
```

Note that this solution is based on the posted code, if there are other widgets in the same row of those entries, it may not work.

Comment: works like a charm! i guess i never knew about grid_slaves. thank you!